# Ethereum contract size limit for multipage contract

Tags: solidity, contract-development, ethereumjs, mainnet, blockchain-size

I got to know that there is a size limitation for Ethereum contract, but to avoid this I split up functions of my contract in two sol files and one contract extends other contract and this solve the size limit problem but I just want to confirm is I am doing anything wrong or I am missing anything?

**For example**

 **Previously** 
File A.sol 
Contract A { 
function f1(){} 
function f2(){} 
function f3(){}
function f4(){}
}

 **Now** 
A.sol 
import "./B.sol"
contract A  is B{
function f3() public {}
function f4() public {}
}
B.sol
contract B{
function f2(){}
function f3(){}
}

Comment: `and one contract extends other contract and this solve the size limit problem` - wrong!

Comment: But  I am not getting any size warning now on remix.

Answer (score 0):

> One contract extends other contract, and this solve the size-limit problem

That's wrong.

When `B` inherits `A`, the entire contents of `A` is included in `B`.

What you want is for `B` to take the address of (an instance of) `A` as input, either in the constructor of `B`, or in every function of `B` which needs to call a function of `A`.

Then, every function of `B` which needs to call a function of `A`, should call it via the address of `A`.